# DataTable Select filterexpression with not 'between'

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to filter a datatable with a price range. I want to remove everything that is not between (for example) 2 and 7. In SQL I would do: NOT( price between 2 and 7). But in my filter expression I cannot use the keyword 'between'. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referencing **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** (which enables LINQ for DataTables), you can do the following:

```
var query = myDataTable.Where(c => !(c.Price >= 2 && c.Price <= 7));
var myDataView = query.AsDataView(); // if you want to databind...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
dt.Select("Price < 2 OR Price > 7")
```

Just rember that

```
price between 2 and 7
```

is equal to

```
price >= 2 AND <= 7
```

and

```
NOT (price between 2 and 7)
```

is equal to

```
price < 2 OR > 7
```