# 'Find' button which can count the number of rows in a table, which consist of DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new in c#.

I need to add a `Find_Click` button which has the functions that can help me to count the number of Rows in a database Table when l key in the value inside the textbox, then display the counted value.

The problem is, the number of rows could not be counted because the values inside are Datetime.

Could anyone help me fix my code? Here it is:

```
private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = FindDateTime.Text;
    int result = 0;
    DataRow[] returnedRows;
    returnedRows = RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["pcPeopleCountingValue"]
                   .Select("ValueDateTime='" + search + "'");

        result = returnedRows.Length;
        if (result > 0)
        {
            DataRow RetailCamDataRow1;
            RetailCamDataRow1 = returnedRows[0];
            MessageBox.Show(returnedRows.Length.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No such Record.");
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line should change to this:

```
 returnedRows = RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["pcPeopleCountingValue"]
               .Select("ValueDateTime=#" + search + "#");
```

Provided your `search` variable has the DateTime in the right format.

---

From your  comment. You can't use `BETWEEN` in the `Select()`  method, instead you could do something like:

```
RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["pcPeopleCountingValue"]
               .Select("ValueDateTime < #" + search" +
                   "00:00:00# AND  ValueDateTime < #" + search +  "23:59:59#");
```

You could also use dataset lambda extensions, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924140/368070

Comment: By using the same code, is it possible to show the counted rows using the BETWEEN and AND? I try to modify the code so that the number of rows of selected date could be counted. Here's my code:
Too bad it turns up EvaluateExceptionUnhandled

returnedRows = RetailCamDataSet1.Tables["pcPeopleCountingValue"].Select("ValueDateTime BETWEEN #" + search + " 00:00:00# AND #" + search + " 23:59:59#");

Comment: Thanks to u again Gideon, l've been digging up google for a week, but still cant find the solution. Yet ur code fixing and info about dataset lambda extension helped me solve my problem.